# Do I need separate graphics card to run Ubuntu Server 14.04?

Tags: server, graphics, gpu

Currently my company has a server running Ubuntu Server 14.04 64 bit with 4 GB of memory and Intel Core i3-2100 processor. And we want to build new a server that will use Intel Xeon E3-1230V3 processor ([see this link](http://ark.intel.com/products/75054/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E3-1230-v3-8M-Cache-3_30-GHz)) and 16 GB of memory.

Since the processor doesn't has integrated graphics, and Ubuntu Server doesn't has a GUI, do I need separate graphics card to run this machine? Does Ubuntu Server needs a graphics processor although it is run on text mode?

Any comments will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a GPU is not necessary for Ubuntu to run on the system. However, if you don't have a serial console or some other management interface with which to visually see what you are doing on the system, you may find it difficult to work through the installation process.